# pangesture in UItableviewcell, table scroll is not working in swift

Tags: uitableview, swipe, uipangesturerecognizer, tinder

I want to swipe UIview left and right inside the UItableviewCell, And I have used UIPanGestureRecognizer to make this happen and below is the attached source code. However when I am trying to scroll UItableview my Uiview is moveable up and down and unable to give scroll to UItableviewcell i.e Superview.Can anyone tell me how to manage? Thanks in advance?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 10

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CardSwipeTVCell") as! CardSwipeTVCell


    let tapGesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer!
    tapGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapEdit(_:)))
    cell.cardView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture!)
    cell.cardView.tag = indexPath.row
    tapGesture!.delegate = self


    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


}

func tapEdit(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
{
    print(recognizer.view?.tag as Any)

    let sender = recognizer.view?.tag as Any

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender as! Int, section: 0)
    let cell = self.cardTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CardSwipeTVCell


    cell?.cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    let card = recognizer.view!
    let point = recognizer.translation(in: view)
    card.center = CGPoint(x: (cell?.center.x)! + point.x, y: (cell?.center.y)! + point.y)

    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

            card.center = (cell?.center)!

        })

    }

}
```

Also another problem is when I tap on the second cell my view got disappeared? Your help will really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if let panGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        //let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: superview!)
        let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(superview)
        if fabs(translation.x) > fabs(translation.y) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    return false
}
```

Add above delegate method in your class. which will stop pangesture while tableview view scrolling vertically.